# Question about designing a particular data structure

Tags: programming, data-structures

Background: I store polygons with a color assigned at the face level. In some occasions I want to use vertex colors but I want to store data efficiently, i.e. don't want to duplicate data to the vertex level when it is not necessary.

Consider the following *simplified* data structure ( I had in mind, but does not work ):

```
 tf := TableForm
 def = {{10, 20}, {30, 40}};
 def2 = Array[def &, 12];
 col = {def2, def2};
 pcl := {{col[[1]], col[[1]], col[[1]], col[[1]]}, {col[[2]], col[[2]]}};

 col[[1]] // tf
 col[[2]] // tf
 pcl[[1]] // tf
 pcl[[2]] // tf
```

`def` represents the data of one instance of a shape;

`def2` represents the data of a shape with p6mm symmetry ( 12 copies );

`col={def, def}` represents the main data structure which currently stores two shapes;

`pcl={{col[[1]], col[[1]], col[[1]], col[[1]]}, {col[[2]], col[[2]]}}` represents the desired data structure which currently stores two shapes with the first having four vertices and the second two vertices;

Now if I set `col[[1,1,1]]` to `{11,21}` this shows up in `pcl`. So far, so good.

I can't however overwrite it at the vertexlevel `pcl[[1,1,1,1]]={12,22}` *Mathematica* generates a `Set::noval: Symbol pcl in part assignment does not have an immediate value. >>` message.

**Question: How do I set up the required data structure** such that a change at the face level propagates through all vertices unless a vertex has been modified for that particular shape?

Comment: Did you check SparseArray and ArrayRules?

Comment: ArrayRules not yet, will do that now.

Comment: Yes, that looks promising! Seems to be the area to handle my problem. Have no experience with SparseArray but will study it.

Comment: What would you like to expect from evaluating something like `pcl[[1,1,All,1]]={{12, 22}, {12, 23}}`? I mean, if you set at once two parts that actually reference the same data? Last wins?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Preamble

I think this is a very good question. Trying to address it in a reasonably general way, I ended up with a tiny framework which implements a  limited form of pointer-like semantics, which I'd like to describe and illustarate.

#### Code

This allows one to mark some portion of the code (some expression) as a reference.

```
ClearAll[Ptr, new, llp];
SetAttributes[{Ptr, new}, HoldAll];
Protect[Ptr, llp];

new[data_] :=
  Module[{st },
    Hold[data] /. p_new :> With[{eval = p}, eval /; True] /.
      Hold[d_] :> (st = Unevaluated[d]) ;
    Ptr[st]
  ];
```

This returns the lowest-level "pointer" inside a given expression containing a given part, if any, with a number of residual indices needed to extract that part.

```
Clear[llptr];
llptr[p_Ptr] := {p, 0};
llptr[expr_] := llp;
llptr[p : Ptr[s_], ind_, inds___] :=
  Block[{llp = {p, Length[{inds}] + 1}}, llptr[s, ind, inds]];
llptr[expr_, ind_, inds___] := llptr[expr[[ind]], inds];
```

This implements a special assignment operator which can work with the "pointers", including part assignments:

```
ClearAll[set];
SetAttributes[set, HoldFirst];
set[Part[expr_, inds__], rhs_] := 
   With[{lp = llptr[expr, inds]},
      (lp /. {p : Ptr[s_], num_} :> 
        (s[[Sequence @@ Take[{inds}, -num]]] = rhs)) /; 
            First[lp] =!= llp];

set[lhs_, rhs_] :=
   With[{l = lhs},
     Replace[l, Ptr[s_] :> Remove[s]];
     Set[lhs, rhs]];
```

This implements a custom `Part` operator, which has special semantics on "pointers":

```
ClearAll[part];
part[expr_, inds : PatternSequence[_, __]] :=
    Fold[part, expr, {inds}];
part[Ptr[s_], ind_] := part[s, ind];
part[expr_, ind_] := expr[[ind]];
```

In particular, any number of reference layers is invisible for the `part`, so the results of `part` should be the same as those of `Part` on expression not containing references but otherwise the same.

This performs a complete "dereferencing" of an expression, converting it to a "normal" one:

```
ClearAll[derefAll];
derefAll[expr_] := expr //. Ptr[s_] :> s
```

#### Illustration

I take your example with slightly smaller sizes of elements to keep this managable here. This is how it would look:

```
tf := TableForm
def ~ set ~ new@{{10, 20}, {30, 40}};
def2 ~ set ~ new@Array[def &, 4];
col ~ set ~ new@{def2, def2};
pcl ~ set ~ new@{{part[col, 1], part[col, 1]}, {part[col, 2]}};
```

Now, some examples:

```
pcl

(* Ptr[st$1074] *)

part[pcl,1]

(*  {Ptr[st$1072],Ptr[st$1072]}  *)

part[pcl,1,1]

(*  Ptr[st$1072]  *)

part[pcl,1,1]//derefAll

(*  {{{10,20},{30,40}},{{10,20},{30,40}},{{10,20},{30,40}},{{10,20},{30,40}}} *)

part[pcl,1,1,1]

(*  Ptr[st$1071]  *)

derefAll@part[pcl,1,1,1]

(*   {{10,20},{30,40}}  *)
```

For parts below the lowest-level pointer, you don't need dereferencing:

```
part[pcl,1,1,1,1]

{10,20}

part[pcl,1,1,1,1,1]

(* 10  *)

part[pcl,1,1,1,1,2]

(* 20 *)
```

Now we reset some part to something else:

```
pcl[[1,1,1]]~set~new@{new@{50,60},new@{70,80}}

(* Ptr[st$1175] *)
```

And check:

```
derefAll@pcl

(*  
    {{{{{50,60},{70,80}},{{50,60},{70,80}},{{50,60},{70,80}},{{50,60},{70,80}}},
    {{{50,60},{70,80}},{{50,60},{70,80}},{{50,60},{70,80}},{{50,60},{70,80}}}},
    {{{{50,60},{70,80}},{{50,60},{70,80}},{{50,60},{70,80}},{{50,60},{70,80}}}}}
*)
```

We see that it propagated to all parts. Now we change it in a different way, through a variable:

```
def2=new@Array[def&,3];
derefAll@pcl

(*
     {{{{{50,60},{70,80}},{{50,60},{70,80}},{{50,60},{70,80}}},
     {{{50,60},{70,80}},{{50,60},{70,80}},{{50,60},{70,80}}}},
     {{{{50,60},{70,80}},{{50,60},{70,80}},{{50,60},{70,80}}}}}
*)
```

We see that again, the change propagated properly. Now we change some other variable:

```
def~set~new@{{1,2},{3,4}}

(* Ptr[st$1219] *)
```

and

```
derefAll@pcl

(* 
    {{{{{1,2},{3,4}},{{1,2},{3,4}},{{1,2},{3,4}}},
    {{{1,2},{3,4}},{{1,2},{3,4}},{{1,2},{3,4}}}},
    {{{{1,2},{3,4}},{{1,2},{3,4}},{{1,2},{3,4}}}}}
*)
```

we see that again the changes propagated. Here is some part of a new expression:

```
part[pcl,1,1,1]//derefAll

(* {{1,2},{3,4}} *)
```

We now change the part by a part assignment:

```
pcl[[1,1,1]]~set~new@{{5,6},{7,8}}

(* Ptr[st$1250] *)
```

What is interesting, and it shows some consistency of our approach, that this change propagated to the variables:

```
def//derefAll

(* {{5,6},{7,8}} *)
```

And again:

```
pcl[[1,1,1,1]]~set~{9,10}

(* {9,10} *)

def//derefAll

(*  {{9,10},{7,8}} *)
```

#### Remarks and conclusions

I have presented a tiny framework implementing a limited version of the pointer semantics. It allows one to introduce mutable state within expressions and propagate changes in a relatively straightforward manner.

The weakest point currently is garbage collection. I have a very primitive form of it implemented in `set` assignment, but I can easily imagine cases where some dangling symbols may be created. I hope to improve on that in the future, if there is enough interest for this.

Comment: What a well written and documented answer! Still, this is Mathematica for Pro's, I'll take the time to carefully study it ( and implement it in my program. ) - I'll make new questions to follow up on this. - Thank you very much, Leonid.

Comment: @ndroock1 As always, glad I could help, and thanks for the accept. Actually, I've made a few attempts to implement something like this over the years, but my previous attempts were much messier. A well-formulated test problem and requirements bring us half-way to the answer, and you've provided a good set-up.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I'd be interested in your garbage collection solution.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this (draft)

```
c = Red;
pcl := {c, Blue};

Module[{preserve, pcl1},
 reset[] := (pcl1 = pcl; preserve = {});
 reset[];
 SetAttributes[set, HoldAll];
 set[element_, value_] :=
  (AppendTo[preserve, {element, value}]; 
   pcl1 = pcl; (pcl1[[#[[1]]]] = #[[2]]) & /@ preserve);
 print[] := preserve;
 get[] := (pcl1 = pcl; (pcl1[[#[[1]]]] = #[[2]]) & /@ preserve; pcl1);
 ]
reset[];
```

[image]