# Is there an equivalent to defstruct in Lisp for Mathematica?

Tags: functions, programming

I guess I am used to using data structures in most languages, the closest function for Mathematica would be similar to the defstruct macro in Lisp... is there such a thing?

Comment: What does defstruct do?

Comment: It creates a set of function to access list elements, say you have a structure named aStruct with elements {arg1, arg2, arg3). defstruct defines functions that access these elements directly

Comment: The macro function `defineAccessors` from [(13722)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13722/142) is like a lightweight version of _defstruct_.

Comment: @guymadison For the need you describe, what is the gain over an Association, which effectively comes with accessors?  (Type checking could be handled by a constructor, if that's the issue.)