# Is there anything like a C pointer (or returning a reference) in $Mathematica$?

Tags: programming, evaluation

I want to do in *Mathematica* what the following does in C.

```c
int array[7] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

int& foo(size_t idx)
{
    return array[idx];
}

foo(4) = 43;

// array should now be {0, 0, 0, 0, 43, 0, 0}
```

In other words, I'd like to use `=` to assign to a reference (to some variable outside the scope of the function) returned by a function.

I did read a few threads about references, but it seemed I'd have to "overload" the `=` operator (if that's even possible) to make things work.

---

#### Background

I wouldn't be surprised if such practice were discouraged in *Mathematica*, but would still appreciate the knowledge, as well as alternatives. My motivation for this is in trying to write a tool for non-programmers (or those with mostly C backgrounds but completely unfamiliar to *Mathematica*) for rapid testing of hypotheses, and the tool must be *intuitive, familiar, and easy to pick up* (else I'm afraid my pitch to use *Mathematica* wouldn't gain traction). To be more specific, the tool would analyze time-series data, the user specifying an expression to be run per time-step; and that expression would have "access" to a (pseudo-)array, say, `price`, such that `price[0]` refers to the *current* price, `price[-1]` refers to the *previous* price, etc.—so `price[0]` refers to a different price at each timestep. Of course C doesn't allow negative indexing; I just thought it'd be most intuitive that way—so my plan was to implement `price` as a function, and retrieve values from an array behind-the-scenes. You can probably see already where this is going: I'd also like for users to be able to *assign* to `price[0]`, and that's where I'm stuck. I know I could (and perhaps *should*) just write a separate function like `set_price[0, val]`, but this would take away from the aesthetic goal I'm trying to achieve to win everyone over.

I'm open to alternative ideas that may keep aesthetic though not in the same way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to modify function argument?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17767/how-to-modify-function-argument)

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I don't think that is a duplicate, as this case is about modifying a known external symbol, not treating the argument as a symbol. That comment section linked to a ton of interesting questions though :) There are plenty of Set overloading questions that I can't seem to find.

Comment: Related [Alternative to overloading Set](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1162/alternative-to-overloading-set)

Comment: @ssch Yes, you are probably right. Then indeed, there were a number of attempts usually involving `UpValues`, like in your answer. One relevant post that comes to mind is [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2651/how-to-pass-a-symbol-name-to-a-function-with-any-of-the-hold-attributes/2677#2677), but there were many more.

Comment: Some time ago I made an emulation of something like a pointer, in my answer to [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8491/question-about-designing-a-particular-data-structure). May be, you may find it useful.

Comment: These two questions seem relevant: [1](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19313/3066) and [2](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19445/3066)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look at [UpValues](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/AssociatingDefinitionsWithDifferentSymbols.html):

```
ClearAll[price];
l = ConstantArray[0, 10];
pos = 5;
price[i_] := l[[pos + i]]
price /: (price[i_] = val_) := (l[[pos + i]] = val)

price[0]=-1;
price[{-2,-1,1}]={1,2,3};

l
(* {0, 0, 1, 2, -1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0} *)
```