# Passing a joined list of symbols for Module or Block to treat as its own local symbols

Tags: functions, evaluation, scoping, hold

#### The Question

I'd like to write a function which itself takes a list of symbols, *e.g.*

```
Foo[{x, y, z}]
```

to pass to `Module` within, but with additional localized symbols, *e.g.*

```
Foo[list_, expr_] := Module[Join[list, {a, b, c}], ...]
```

In other words, I'd like `Foo[{x, y, z}]` to behave like

```
Module[{x, y, z, a, b, c}, ...]
```

#### To show what I've tried, though all in vain...

I started without the `Join`:

```
ClearAll[x, y, z, a, b, c, Foo];
x = 7;
Foo[vars_] := Module[vars, x = 43];
Foo[{x, y, z}];
x
```

which returned, understandably,

```
Module::lvsym: "Local variable specification {7,y,z} contains 7, which is not a symbol or an assignment to a symbol."
```

I added `SetAttributes`,

```
ClearAll[x, y, z, a, b, c, Foo];
x = 7;
SetAttributes[Foo, HoldAll];
Foo[vars_] := Module[vars, x = 43];
Foo[{x, y, z}];
x
```

which returned the desired result, `43`, *i.e.* unchanged by the assignment within the `Module`.

Now, including a `Join`,

```
ClearAll[x, y, z, a, b, c, Foo];
x = 7;
SetAttributes[Foo, HoldAll];
Foo[vars_] := Module[Join[vars, {a, b, c}], x = 43];
Foo[{x, y, z}];
x
```

I got,

```
Module::lvlist: "Local variable specification Join[{x,y,z},{a,b,c}] is not a List."
```

As I understand, the `Join` didn't evaluate because `Module` itself must be putting a `Hold` attribute on (at least, if not more than) its first argument. So, reading that `Evaluate`

> effectively overrides the `HoldFirst` attribute, and causes the first argument to be evaluated,

I tried

```
ClearAll[x, y, z, a, b, c, Foo];
x = 7;
SetAttributes[Foo, HoldAll];
Foo[vars_] := Module[Evaluate[Join[vars, {a, b, c}]], x = 43];
Foo[{x, y, z}];
x
```

which returned

```
Module::lvsym: "Local variable specification {7,y,z,a,b,c} contains 7, which is not a symbol or an assignment to a symbol."
```

I'm a bit confused as to why `x` interpolated, *i.e.* why the `Hold` attribute didn't persist. I guess the `Hold` attribute only "carries" the argument, unevaluated, into the function, but doesn't hold the argument beyond? Okay, then should I `Hold` the list again?

```
ClearAll[x, y, z, a, b, c, Foo];
x = 7;
SetAttributes[Foo, HoldAll];
Foo[vars_] := Module[Evaluate[Join[Hold[vars], {a, b, c}]], x = 43];
Foo[{x, y, z}];
x
```

This resulted in:

```
Join::heads: Heads Hold and List at positions 1 and 2 are expected to be the same.

Module::lvlist: "Local variable specification Join[Hold[{x,y,z}],{a,b,c}] is not a List."
```

I made sure to read both [Evaluation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/Evaluation.html) and [Non-Standard Evaluation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NonStandardEvaluation.html), but unfortunately these didn't (seem to) help me understand what's happening. I tried `Unevaluated` and `Defer` just to try, but the results weren't different. I saw a Google Groups thread where the solution seemed to be somehow converting the symbols to strings, then back via `Symbol`, but I thought there must be a better way...

---

#### Background

@SjoerdCdeVries, in short, I'm trying to write a sort of a `While` loop that makes certain convenient symbols (both functions and variables) available to use within (and only within) the looping expression, and also displaying certain results of the loop afterwards. The motivation is sort-of-explained in the "Background" section of [Is there anything like a C pointer (or returning a reference) in $Mathematica$?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34850/is-there-anything-like-a-c-pointer-or-returning-a-reference-in-mathematica); I'm writing a tool that users (mostly familiar with `C`, only) can use to prototype ideas for analyzing time-series data.

I have a more specific use-case example (in code), but I've decided not to share this unless requested—this post is long enough already.

Comment: Where would you use this for?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries - Added some background. Initially I included a use-case, but perhaps the concise summary is enough. Let me know if not.

Comment: If you want to do a pass-by-reference you could use the `Hold` attribute (see http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/17770/57).

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries - Well, that's where I'm stuck; I don't seem to know how to use `Hold` properly in this case. But perhaps you're saying my answer is in that link; I'll give it a read right now. [...] This is going to take me some time to read (all the related links too) but I believe I'll find my answer. Thanks!

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries - The whole code-injection thing was eye-opening. LeonidShifrin uses a new symbol `x1` to localize an existing one `x`; maybe it's not possible to do this using the same symbol (which would explain my futile efforts). One of the comments in that question led to [this thread](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2651/how-to-pass-a-symbol-name-to-a-function-with-any-of-the-hold-attributes/2677#2677), which was a slightly different problem in that it began with string names of symbols, not symbols, but OleksandrR. presents a function `referenceTo` that can handle both

Comment: string names of symbols as well as symbols themselves. Unfortunately, my several attempts to copy and use his function failed, and though I've tried, I'm not yet able to understand his code (I didn't even know what `/:` was before beginning to inspect his code) enough to debug what's wrong. For now, I've given up, and gone after the trivial solution: using a `Module` inside another `Module`, since I _am_ able to pass symbols along as unmodified lists... I just can't seem to modify the function arguments.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to do, but does this work for you? `Foo[vars_] := Hold[vars] /. _@{v__} :> Module[{v, a, b, c}, x = 43]`

Comment: @SimonWoods - Wow, that's it! If I weren't so new to this idea of pattern replacement, maybe I could have thought that up (or maybe not). I'm still stuck on a C++ way of thinking. Would you post this as an answer, please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can "inject" your variables into the module like this:

```
ClearAll[x, y, z, a, b, c, Foo];
x = 7;
SetAttributes[Foo, HoldAll];
Foo[vars_] := Hold[vars] /. _@{v__} :> Module[{v, a, b, c}, x = 43]

Foo[{x, y, z}]
(* 43 *)

x
(* 7 *)
```

For more information have a look at some of the questions and answers in these search results:
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=injector