# Is there any way to assign multiple values?

Tags: programming, assignment

I am looking for something like "**byref**" assignment in programming languages.

Let's assume I have:

> x1=x2=....=xn

if I want to change their values ( say to 3 ) I need to set all of them like:

> x1=x2=...=xn=3

Is there any way that I can change just one value ( as xn=3 ), and all others change simultaneously?

For those who are familiar with programming languages it is easy to understand: assign x1..xn as "byref" and changing just one value, will change all others. In large assignments it will reduce a lot of the work load.

Is there any similar ways in the Mathematica?

Comment: A search for "pointers in Mathematica" turns up lots of discussion related to this question. Seems that it's more involved than it might appear at first glance due to the way Mathematica handles data typing. A workable solution is presented in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8491/question-about-designing-a-particular-data-structure/8496#8496) and a different approach is shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6691491/implementing-a-quadtree-in-mathematica/6795762#6795762).

Answer (score 7):

You can delay-set the variables of interest to a common variable:

```
Table[x[k] := m, {k, 10}];
m = 4;
Table[x[k], {k, 10}]
m = 3;
Table[x[k], {k, 10}]
```

which produces output

```
{4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4}
{3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3}
```

This way, whenever `m` is altered, the rest of the `x[k]` adapt accordingly.

I'm not quite sure how to make it so that altering one of the `x[i]` alters the rest of the `x[k]`, though. Maybe someone else can post an answer which handles that, in case the use of a common variable is somehow not usable for you.

Answer (score 6):

You can "unify" several variables in the following way

```
x /: HoldPattern[x[k_] = val_] /; 1 <= k <= 10 := (shared = val)
x[k_] /; 1 <= k <= 10 && ValueQ[shared] := shared

x[2]
(* x[2] *)

x[3] = 1
(* 1 *)

x[9]
(* 1 *)

x[8] = 0
(* 0 *)

x[7]
(* 0 *)

x[2] = x[3] + 1   (* like shared++ *)
(* 1 *)

x[11]
(* x[11] *)
```

---

The same for uncounted variables is a bit more complicated

```
SetAttributes[unify, HoldAll];
unify[vars__] := If[Not@ValueQ@shared@Unevaluated[vars], 
     Function[v, v /: HoldPattern[v = val_] := (shared@Unevaluated[vars] = val);
       v /; ValueQ@shared@Unevaluated[vars] := shared@Unevaluated[vars],
         HoldAll] /@ Unevaluated@{vars};]

unify[a, b, c]

a
(* a *)

b = 1
(* 1 *)

c
(* 1 *)

unify[d, e]

d = 2
(* 2 *)

a  (* sets are independent *)
(* 1 *)

ClearAll[a, b, c] (* destruct unify[a, b, c] *)
ClearAll[d, e]
```

Comment: +1, this definitely seems to better address the original question than my answer, although the pattern-matching syntax is pretty mind-bending!

Comment: Actually, do you think you could briefly explain the use of `/:` in your first example? I'm having trouble understanding the documentation page for `TagSet`.

Comment: Darn clever.  Note that `unify[a, f]` doesn't work as perhaps desired: `a = 4; a` does not result in `4`.  (Executed in turn after the above.)  OTOH, I don't really understand the OP's use case of having several identifiers refer to the same value (or variable).  I thought "byref" had to do with function parameters....

Comment: @MichaelE2 "by ref" and "by value" are the two main parameter-passing strategies. Some languages implement both. What do you push into the stack when you are going to call a function? the parameter's values or the parameter's memory pointer? If the later, the receiving function code may alter the "variables" on the caller end (AKA side effects)

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus It is almost like `UpSet` but with manually selected tag. It is a bad idea to redefine `Set` so I define `UpValues` for my variables.

Comment: @belisarius But I don't understand what parameter passing has to do with the OP's question.

Comment: @MichaelE2 A simultaneous usage of one variable in different `unify` has undefined behavior. You can `ClearAll[a,b,c]` to destruct `unify`. I assume that OP has a program with different variable and he/she wants to unify several variables without rewriting the program. I think one can find interesting examples of the runtime unifying of different sets of variables.

Comment: @MichaelE2 In languages that allow "by ref" it's also common to be able to assign pointers. So you may say `<memory pointer to var a> == <memory pointer to var b>` so effectively making `a`and `b` to use the same memory address.

Comment: @belisarius and ybeltukov - Thanks, it's clear now.

Answer (score 1):

You could define a function which creates an array of n constant value

```
var[constant_, n_] := x = ConstantArray[constant, n]
```

For e.g we can make an array of size 5 having 3 as the constant value for all elements as follows

```
var[3, 5]
(*{3, 3, 3, 3, 3}*)
```

Since x is equated to this function you can call each array element as follows

```
x[[1]] 
(*3*)
```

So now if you want to change the constant from 3 to 4 you just call the function

```
var[4, 5]
(*{4, 4, 4, 4, 4}*)
```

This will effectively change all the x values

```
x[[1]] 
(*4*)
```

Answer (score 0):

If xn has not yet a value,

```
x1=x2=...=xn
```

will set all variables to `xn`, and then if you do

```
xn=3
```

all of them will evaluate to `3`.

If `xn` already has a value at the point of assignment, you can temporarily unset it using `Block`. For example

```
c=1
Block[{c}, a=b=c]
{a, b, c}
(*
==> {1, 1, 1}
*)
c=2
{a, b, c}
(*
==> {2, 2, 2}
*)
```

However, in that case the better option would be to do individual assignments using the standard `SetDelayed`:

```
a := c; b := c
```

This always works, even if `c` is already assigned a value.

Note however that this only works for assignments to c; assignments to a or b will not propagate to the other variables. To achieve that, you can additionally do

```
a /: (a=x_) := c=x
```

and the same with `b`. Basically this tells Mathematica that whenever it sees an expression of the form `a=expression` it should execute `c=expression`. Note however that this is not a catch-all; it doesn't cover other ways `a` might get a value assigned; the most obvious being `:=`. You'd have to find out a complete set of ways how `a` might be changed and write a replacement rule for each of them (assuming this is possible; in some cases, `a` might be buried too deeply in the expression). In the end, it's probably a better idea to just restrict assignments to be done on `c`.